# starting hadoop on mac os lion

Tags: mac-osx, hadoop

I want to start hadoop on my macbook pro, I did all the steps that apache says. When I use the command "bin/start-all.sh", I get this:

```
starting namenode, logging to /Users/alibozorgkhan/Desktop/hadoop-0.20.203.0/bin/../logs/hadoop-alibozorgkhan-namenode-d142-058-172-111.wireless.sfu.ca.out
localhost: starting datanode, logging to /Users/alibozorgkhan/Desktop/hadoop-0.20.203.0/bin/../logs/hadoop-alibozorgkhan-datanode-d142-058-172-111.wireless.sfu.ca.out
localhost: starting secondarynamenode, logging to /Users/alibozorgkhan/Desktop/hadoop-0.20.203.0/bin/../logs/hadoop-alibozorgkhan-secondarynamenode-d142-058-172-111.wireless.sfu.ca.out
starting jobtracker, logging to /Users/alibozorgkhan/Desktop/hadoop-0.20.203.0/bin/../logs/hadoop-alibozorgkhan-jobtracker-d142-058-172-111.wireless.sfu.ca.out
localhost: starting tasktracker, logging to /Users/alibozorgkhan/Desktop/hadoop-0.20.203.0/bin/../logs/hadoop-alibozorgkhan-tasktracker-d142-058-172-111.wireless.sfu.ca.out
```

Hadoop doesn't start. I checked the log for datanode and it has this:

```
2011-10-06 18:03:45,513 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.createSocketAddr(NetUtils.java:136)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.getAddress(NameNode.java:176)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.getAddress(NameNode.java:206)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.getServiceAddress(NameNode.java:200)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.startDataNode(DataNode.java:306)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.<init>(DataNode.java:268)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.makeInstance(DataNode.java:1480)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.instantiateDataNode(DataNode.java:1419)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.createDataNode(DataNode.java:1437)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.secureMain(DataNode.java:1563)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.main(DataNode.java:1573)
```

Any idea how to fix this? Thanx

Comment: Probably you haven't defined a data node? Or made a typo in it?

Comment: Thanx for your comment. I found the problem. I didn't customize the xml files in conf folder.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of years ago I installed Hadoop on my MacbookPro to do testing. It was a bad idea. Took me about five hours to get everything running. It needs the proper Java versions, proper PATH settings, proper HDFS/Hadoop settings and versions.

Since I don't need performance to do testing I switched to using a virtual machine shortly afterwards. There are tons and tons of free VMs just a Google search away, which can be run using free VM players.